# How to load non-default version of python in command line

Tags: python, linux

I have 2 different versions of python installed on my system i.e. 2.6.6 and 2.7.9.
I am running python scripts on linux via QTP(using paramiko on windows). I execute the following sample of code to execute commands.
"python /dir/of/frameword/ somecode"

When I hit this command the default version of python is used to create the shell that is 2.6.6
Is there any way that I could instruct the linux to pick up 2.7.9 with a command like "python27". 
I have also added an alias in ./bashrc but that also dosent help.

Comment: Install the two versions in different folders, eg. Python2 and Python3. Use singly or a mixture of shebangs, aliases or default paths.  I have done this with perl.

Answer (score 0):

1. set up a shell alias

`alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`

PS:have you run `source ~/.bashrc` after save ~/.bashrc?I noticed you mention ./bashrc instead of ~/.bashrc,is it a spelling mistake?

2. use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: I have run  source ~/.bashrc even then the subshells are created(like python subprocess) are created using default version

Comment: It's strange.run `/path/to/python2.7  /dir/of/frameword/somecode` still doesn't work?